# How to debug slow running stock install of Laravel 4 on Cpanel

Tags: php, laravel-4, cpanel

I've installed an out-of-the-box L4 project on both my local workstation and on my production Cpanel server. It has no database connectivity and I'm just hitting the stock home page with Laravel logo. My local install responds in 80ms or less, however the production server that is far more powerful takes between 2.5 - 8 seconds to respond. It's awful slow.

Debug is False. Every once in a while I'll get a fast response, but I can't make sense of it's randomness, The server is a powerhouse with 8 cores and 16 GB of RAM. It only hosts one other website. I can pull up the robots.txt or phpinfo file instantly, so it's not just a server issue. Here's the staging site that I'm working on: http://staging.dirtondirt.com/

How can I figure out or debug where the slowdown is?

Comment: Taking a guess that Laravel probably caches the classes (or at least so it can autoload them), perhaps it can't save its cache so it needs to do some sort of scan or class lookup every request? (Make sure it has write permissions to where it normally saves its cache) I would have assumed DB connectivity as an issue though you pointed out that isn't the case. Disclaimer: Never used Laravel, just taking a guess from experience with other systems.

Comment: I thought that first, so I made sure write permissions were set. It seems to be writing cache files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the popular Laravel DebugBar - 
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/tree/1.8

In this, it gives you a 'timeline' of aspects of your application, so you can see what is causing the slow load times.

If that fails - another option is [Blackfire.io](https://blackfire.io/) - which is a new service - I havent tried it yet, but they support Laravel.

Comment: Yeah, I was holding back on installing another package, but I may have to install Barry's debugger in order to figure this out.

Comment: Once you work out the issue - you can then uninstall the package - you dont need to leave it there...

Comment: @Corgalore - did this help? Did you solve your problem? Or do you need more info?

Comment: The Debug Bar did not help in this case. I believe the problem is related to the PHP handler set in CPanel, which is suPHP. It does not allow any opcode caching so I believe that's hurting Laravel quite a bit due to it's large framework. I will post my results after switching to FastCGI and enabling an opcode cache.

Comment: Do you need to use cPanel? Can you switch hosts? Using Laravel Forge - you can be up and running on a new box in no time...

Comment: I know, trust me. The customer is stuck in a contract. Plus they have a terabyte of old videos on there and email boxes.

Comment: But you can leave the old data + email boxes on the current server - and just route the www traffic to another IP address. I've done this before for a customer who is also stuck on cPanel. This way they have no outage, no email migration - just the www domain is moved.

Comment: Problem is they would get billed for two servers : (  I would love to do what you're saying.